# ThreeTen-Backport error on Android - ZoneRulesException: No time-zone data files registered

Tags: java, android, exception, jsr310, threetenbp

I'm using ThreeTen-Backport library for my Android project (because java.time is not yet implemented in android development).

When I write `LocalDate today=LocalDate.now();` or `LocalTime time=LocalTime.now();` I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesException: 
  No time-zone data files registered   
      at org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getProvider(ZoneRulesProvider.java:176)
      at org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getRules(ZoneRulesProvider.java:133)
      at org.threeten.bp.ZoneRegion.ofId(ZoneRegion.java:143)
      at org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:357)
      at org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:285)
      at org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.systemDefault(ZoneId.java:244)
      at org.threeten.bp.Clock.systemDefaultZone(Clock.java:137)
      at org.threeten.bp.LocalDate.now(LocalDate.java:165)
```

The same line of code works well in another java project I have, which uses the native java.time library.

I searched for a possible solution but couldn't find anything useful: one solution suggested I need to use another jar that includes the time-zone rules and other suggested that there might be two or more ThreeTenBP-libraries inside the classpath.
Those cases don't match my case.

Inside the `build.gradle` file, at the dependencies section, I've tried few configurations:

- At first, I used - `compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.3'`
- Then, I tried -
  `compile 'org.threeten:threetenbp:1.0.3'`
- After that, I tried -
  `compile 'org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.1'`
- Currently, I use `compile 'org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.2'`

I don't know what is wrong with that line of code and how to fix it.
The `LocalDate.now()` and `LocalTime.now()` methods should work without specifying a time zone.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

For Android project you should use

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.3'
```

Make sure you call `AndroidThreeTen.init(this);` before using the classes from the library. This will read the time zones data (included in the library). You can initialize the library in your `Application` class in the `onCreate` method just like it is recommended in the [README](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Comment: Thank you, my project didn't have an application class before, so I wasn't able to use the `AndroidThreeTen.init(this);` code. I thought to add this in the activity's `onCreate` method but I saw it wasn't right.  
Now I've created a new class which extends the application class and put that line in the `onCreate` method. Now everything works just great!

Comment: Calling init in onCreate violates strictmode and can even delay app startup. If you call init asynchronously, you have to make sure not to use it until it completes, which can be difficult for JUnit testing.

Comment: @ErikB it does violate strict mode because it reads the time zones file from assets so it delays startup time. For unit tests you should use the original library http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/ because this one has Android dependencies as explained here https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP/issues/14

Comment: How to initialize this library in a Unit test?

Comment: You don't. You just add the original one for unit tests (`testImplementation`) and you are good to go

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/55343062/108742 was useful to make it work in unit tests 

Answer (score 3):

Instead of initialization of the library, you can try this:

**LocalDateEx.kt**

```
object LocalDateEx {
    /**an alternative of LocalDate.now(), as it requires initialization using AndroidThreeTen.init(context), which takes a bit time (loads a file)*/
    @JvmStatic
    fun getNow(): LocalDate = Calendar.getInstance().toLocalDate()
}

fun Calendar.toLocalDate(): LocalDate = LocalDate.of(get(Calendar.YEAR), get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
```

**LocalTimeEx.kt**

```
object LocalTimeEx {
    /**an alternative of LocalDateTime.now(), as it requires initialization using AndroidThreeTen.init(context), which takes a bit time (loads a file)*/
    @JvmStatic
    fun getNow(): LocalTime = Calendar.getInstance().toLocalTime()
}

fun Calendar.toLocalTime(): LocalTime = LocalTime.of(get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), get(Calendar.MINUTE), get(Calendar.SECOND), get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) * 1000000)
```

**LocalDateTimeEx.kt**

```
object LocalDateTimeEx {
    /**an alternative of LocalDateTime.now(), as it requires initialization using AndroidThreeTen.init(context), which takes a bit time (loads a file)*/
    @JvmStatic
    fun getNow(): LocalDateTime = Calendar.getInstance().toLocalDateTime()
}

private fun Calendar.toLocalDateTime(): LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(get(Calendar.YEAR), get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), get(Calendar.MINUTE), get(Calendar.SECOND),
        get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) * 1000000)
```

Usage:

```
   val today=LocalDateEx.getNow()
   val today2=LocalTimeEx.getNow()
   val today3=LocalDateTimeEx.getNow()
```

Comment: this is very useful for compose previews or tests

Answer (score 2):

For me, it wasn't working on signed release build with proguard enabled. Check your proguard rules if they contain

```
-keep class org.threeten.bp.zone.*
```

unless, add it. It helped for me.

Answer (score 2):

When I was using API 25 *java.time* did not work. Using Jake Wharton's threetenadp did. So here's a slight update to use it on Studio 2020.3.1

In the module build.gradle

```
dependencies {
 implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.3.1'
}
```

---

```
import com.jakewharton.threetenabp.AndroidThreeTen
```

---

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    AndroidThreeTen.init(application);
```

When the IDE asks to import, be sure to choose *com.jakewharton.threetenabp.AndroidThreeTen* and not *java.time*

LocalTime.now().toSecondOfDay() is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

AGP 4.0 now support Java 8 Desugar API, see here: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

So you can use `java.time.` without using a backported version

NOTES:

There's still an issue if you trying to support API below 21 (solved by `minSdk 21`): https://github.com/google/bundletool/issues/182#issuecomment-753269941

Desugaring will also increase builds time as stated in the official docs

> To support these language APIs, the plugin compiles a separate DEX file that contains an implementation of the missing APIs and includes it in your app. The desugaring process rewrites your app’s code to instead use this library at runtime.