# AndroidThreeTen not working in unit test without robolectric?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, kotlin, robolectric

I'm having trouble creating a unit test without needing robolectric.  I am using AndroidThreeTen.init(this) in my code and when I run my test if I disable robolectric I get an error:
`org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesException: No time-zone data files registered`

and if I leave it enabled I get this:
`[Robolectric] com.mycomp.,yapp.utilities.log.LogTest.on Calling function w it returns an Int: sdk=28; resources=BINARY`

I have tried using testImplementation ‘com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.0’
made no difference.  I have AndroidThreeTen.init(this) called in my application and testApplication. any ideas?
this is my test

```
@Test
    fun `on Calling function i it returns an Int`() {
        assertThat("Returned class is not an Int", Log.i("Test", "Test"), isA(Int::class.java))
        assertThat("Returned Int is not 0", Log.i("Test", "Test"), `is`(0))
    }
```

Or do I have to use robolectric because of this?
(Side note: Log is not the util.log from android but my own class) (edited)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

JVM unit tests don't run on Android runtime. Instead of ThreeTenABP, you can just use ThreeTenBP directly to get the same API initialised for a regular JVM.

In my project build.gradle I use a setup like:

```
implementation "com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:${threetenabpVersion}"
testImplementation("org.threeten:threetenbp:${threetenbpVersion}") {
    exclude module: "com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:${threetenabpVersion}"
}
```

where

```
threetenabpVersion = '1.2.0'
threetenbpVersion = '1.3.8'
```

This uses ThreeTenBP via ThreeTenABP normally, but in unit test configuration it adds TreeTenBP directly as a dependency, with its init code. Cannot remember exactly why I put in the `exclude` rule; it's been like that for a few years already.

Comment: As I am very new to unit testing and all of this.  I implemented this but not exactly sure what it does?

Comment: Added some explanation.

Comment: Awesome, very helpful.  thank you now on to the next issue/error that popped up lol

Answer (score 0):

For some reason [@laalto solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55343062/6136131) didn't work for me. Here's what worked instead:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:$threetenabp_version"
    testImplementation "org.threeten:threetenbp:$threetenbp_version"
}

configurations.testImplementation {
    exclude group: 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp'
}
```