# How to fix "Call requires API level 26 (current min is 25) " error in Android

Tags: java, android, localdate, localtime

I know this question may be duplicated but I didn't find any answer for my problem, I'm using `LocalDateTime` in my Android app that requires API 26 and my device's API is 25.

What can I do? Your help will be very appreciated.

Comment: It is quite obvious that you can't use newer features on older devices. You have to either implement this feature by yourself, or find a library that provides similar functionality

Comment: Many years have past but I just wanted to point out that the comment by @VladyslavMatviienko is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to use https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP to be able using LocalDateTime with Android API < 26.

Add the dependencies to your project (please follow the project README):

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.1'
```

Then change your `LocalDateTime` import from:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
```

to:

```
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime;
```

and please do not forget to call `AndroidThreeTen.init(this)` in your Application class `onCreate` method like;

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        AndroidThreeTen.init(this);
    }

}
```

---

### Update:

The library mentioned above is no longer the best way as mentioned in [JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) README:

> Attention: Development on this library is winding down. Please consider switching to Android Gradle plugin 4.0, java.time.*, and its core library desugaring feature in the coming months.

To use `LocalDateTime` in older API levels, use the desugaring feature from Gradle plugin 4.0:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring

Comment: It is recommended now in the ThreeTenABP repo that you use code desugaring(https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)

Comment: look also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281808/threeten-backport-error-on-android-zonerulesexception-no-time-zone-data-files if using timezones

Answer (score 54):

The best way to use `LocalDateTime` on a lower versions of Android is by desugaring (you must have Android Gradle plugin version 4.0 or higher). Just add the below lines to your `app` module gradle file:

[image]

Finally, add the ff. dependency to your dependencies block:

`coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.10'`

Comment: This is recommended way by Google. Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring

Comment: Also, from the Android site: "With Android Gradle plugin 7.4.0 or higher, a number of Java 11 language APIs are also available with desugared library 2.0.0 or higher." These libraries come in three different flavors: minimal, default and nio (this one being the catch-all flavor since it also includes the packages from  the other two).

Answer (score 13):

To use `LocalDateTime` on lower versions of Android is by desugaring (you must have Android Gradle plugin version 4.0 or higher) enable java8 and use the code below in your `app.gradle`

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true // <- this flag is required

        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    // For Kotlin projects
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5") // <- this dependency is required
}
```

[Supporting docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)

Comment: this answer worked for me because with just adding the dependency `coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5")`, I had to put `@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)` above the function that used the code that required API26. Once I added `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true` to the `compileOptions`, I no longer had to do that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ThreeTenBP](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). But for android it is recommended to use Jake Wharton's [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

**Why not use ThreeTenBP?**

> Similar to the problems with using Joda-Time on Android, the threetenbp uses a JAR resource for loading timezone information. This is an extremely inefficient mechanism on Android.
>
> This library places the timezone information as a standard Android asset and provides a custom loader for parsing it efficiently.

**Why not use Joda-Time?**

> Joda-Time has a very large API which brings with it a very large binary size and large method count. The creator of both JSR-310 and Joda-Time has also said that while Joda-Time isn't broken, it does have design flaws.
>
> If you are using Joda-Time already, there's little reason to switch unless its size or method count is relevant to you. For new projects, however, this library offers the standard APIs in Java 8 as a much smaller package in not only binary size and method count, but also in API size.

These explanations came from Jake Wharton's ThreeTenABP.

Comment: I just followed the link you gave me but the error is always there :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true`  as mentioned above but still see the issue is not resolved, check that you have the latest coreLibraryDesugaring version as in my case it was `1.1.1` which upgrading to `1.1.5` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to click 'Sync Project With Gradle Files' for the configurations to take into effect.

This resolves the warning messages that remain.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33310432)