# Compare date time android

Tags: android, kotlin

What is the best way to convert this string to time and compare it to current time in Android?
The string looks like this

`2021-07-10T12:37:52.770268`

For now i just thought about the splitting it base on T so it has date and time, but i dont know how to format and compare this kind of time string.

And how to display the time between them, like 10 minutes ago, 1 hour ago, etc).

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68258560/9346054

Comment: any idea of how to that in lower level api? like 21/22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i created this ext function, based on [**ritesh**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68327419/9516833) and [**Pouria**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68327046/9516833) answer

```
/**
    @return  formatted date from given String
 */
fun String.toDate(): Date? {
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
    return dateFormat.parse(this)
}

/**
    @return  the difference, measure in milliseconds
             between current system time and the time passed to the function
 */
fun Date.compareToCurrentDateTime(): Long {
    val thisTime: Long = this.time
    val currentTime: Long = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return currentTime - thisTime
}

/**
    @return  amount of minutes, in Int
             from given milliseconds value
 */
fun Long.getMinutes(): Int {
    return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(this).toInt()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this code to parse date time string:

```
val dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("12-08-2016T10:20:30.343", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/y HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
```

for comparing two date, you can use `isAfter` and `isBefore` method of datetime. like this:

```
val dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse("12-08-2016T10:20:30.343", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/y HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
val dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.parse("10-07-2016T10:20:30.343", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/y HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
dateTime1.isAfter(dateTime2)
```

**Update:**
You can use the [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56695997/how-to-fix-call-requires-api-level-26-current-min-is-25-error-in-android/56696502) for API less than 26.

Comment: thanks for answering, but it seems that require API 26

Comment: welcome. use this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56695997/how-to-fix-call-requires-api-level-26-current-min-is-25-error-in-android/56696502

Answer (score 1):

you can use these code :

```
String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
String DATE_TIME_WITH_SPACE = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
String DATE_SHORT_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
String DATE_SHORT_FORMAT_WITH_SLASH = "yyyy/MM/dd";
String NORMAL_DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy/MM/dd kk:mm:ss";
String DATE_TIME_MILISECONDS = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss";
String DATE_TIME_MILISCONDS_2 = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss";
String TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm:ss";
String SHORT_TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm";
```

for example code

```
    private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatDATE_TIME_WITH_SPACE = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_WITH_SPACE);   

simpleDateFormatDATE_TIME_WITH_SPACE.parse('your string date', ""));
```

Comment: I tried DATE_TIME_MILISECONDS but does not work

edit: i tried the top one, it works

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to create a extension function for String to convert it into date object:

```
fun String.toDate(): Date? {
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault())
    return dateFormat.parse(this)
}

fun Date.compareToCurrentDateTime() = this.compareTo(Date())
```

Using below method of date class:

```
/**
 * Compares two Dates for ordering.
 *
 * @param   anotherDate   the <code>Date</code> to be compared.
 * @return  the value <code>0</code> if the argument Date is equal to
 *          this Date; a value less than <code>0</code> if this Date
 *          is before the Date argument; and a value greater than
 *      <code>0</code> if this Date is after the Date argument.
 * @since   1.2
 * @exception NullPointerException if <code>anotherDate</code> is null.
 */
public int compareTo(Date anotherDate) {
    long thisTime = getMillisOf(this);
    long anotherTime = getMillisOf(anotherDate);
    return (thisTime<anotherTime ? -1 : (thisTime==anotherTime ? 0 : 1));
}
```

Comment: the compare to only return either 0, 1, or -1. Can i get the milis? because getMilis can not be accessed outside of Date class

Comment: nvm, i created mine. Thanks for the rep :D