# Jetpack Compose Preview failing with LocalDate.now() from ThreeTen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, threetenbp, android-jetpack-compose-preview

Rendering the Jetpack Compose Preview fails when we have some code calling LocalDate.now() from it. We have tried setting a locale on the preview but that does not help, and we have not found any other way to set context information on the Preview.

How can we make that work?

Preview render problem stacktrace:

> org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesException: No time-zone data files
> registered    at
> org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getProvider(ZoneRulesProvider.java:165)
> at
> org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getRules(ZoneRulesProvider.java:122)
> at org.threeten.bp.ZoneRegion.ofId(ZoneRegion.java:143)     at
> org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:358)    at
> org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:286)    at
> org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.systemDefault(ZoneId.java:245)     at
> org.threeten.bp.Clock.systemDefaultZone(Clock.java:137)   at
> org.threeten.bp.LocalDate.now(LocalDate.java:165)     at
> xxx.ui.shared.formatter.OrderDateFormatter.getFormattedTimes(OrderDateFormatter.kt:12)
> at xxx.model.Pickup.displayCreatedTime(Pickup.kt:55)    at
> xxx.ui.orderStatus.pickups.PickupsListKt.DateRows(PickupsList.kt:268)
> at
> xxx.ui.orderStatus.pickups.PickupsListKt.PickupPanelDetails(PickupsList.kt:129)
> at
> xxx.ui.orderStatus.pickups.PickupsListKt.PickupPanel(PickupsList.kt:78)
> at
> xxx.ui.orderStatus.pickups.PickupsListKt$PickupsList$1$1.invoke(PickupsList.kt:51)
> at
> xxx.ui.orderStatus.pickups.PickupsListKt$PickupsList$1$1.invoke(PickupsList.kt:49)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at
> xxx.ui.shared.composables.LoadingComposableKt.LoadingComposable(LoadingComposable.kt:39)
> at
> xxx.ui.orderStatus.pickups.PickupsListKt.PickupsList(PickupsList.kt:49)
> at
> xxx.ui.orderStatus.pickups.ComposableSingletons$PickupsListKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(PickupsList.kt:337)
> at
> xxx.ui.orderStatus.pickups.ComposableSingletons$PickupsListKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(PickupsList.kt:336)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at
> xxx.ui.shared.appTheme.AppThemeKt$AppTheme$1.invoke(AppTheme.kt:56)
> at
> xxx.ui.shared.appTheme.AppThemeKt$AppTheme$1.invoke(AppTheme.kt:55)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
> at androidx.compose.material.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:252)   at
> androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
> at
> androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:80)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
> at
> androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:72)
> at xxx.ui.shared.appTheme.AppThemeKt.AppTheme(AppTheme.kt:55)   at
> xxx.ui.orderStatus.pickups.PickupsListKt.DefaultPickupsListPreview(PickupsList.kt:336)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.CommonPreviewUtils.invokeComposableMethod(CommonPreviewUtils.kt:149)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.CommonPreviewUtils.invokeComposableViaReflection$ui_tooling_release(CommonPreviewUtils.kt:188)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:571)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:569)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:608)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:564)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.InspectableKt.Inspectable(Inspectable.kt:64)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:513)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:512)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:508)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.access$WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:121)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:564)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:561)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:384)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:228)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:227)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:148)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:113)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:106)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:162)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3336)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2583)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2579)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotState.kt:540)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2572)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2523)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:476)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:727)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:432)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:733)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:187)
> at
> androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
> at
> androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:142)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:820)
> at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)
> at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> at
> android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:44)
> at
> com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:360)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:714)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:870)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the call to AndroidThreeTen.init() mandatory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960183/is-the-call-to-androidthreeten-init-mandatory)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And just after posting the question we found a solution.

Just add this line at the start of each preview method needing it:

```
AndroidThreeTen.init(LocalContext.current)
```

It would be nice with a way to setup a method to be called as setup for all previews, it might be something to hope for in comming releases.

Comment: One can argue that a previewable composable should not be dealing with dates and times directly. Something else, such as a viewmodel, would handle the date/time conversion to data that is more directly rendered (e.g., string representations to display, booleans for controlling icons). That improves testability, with a side benefit of not needing to initialize `AndroidThreeTen`.