# Android ThreeTen ABP library not working in unit tests (ZoneRulesException)

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, threetenbp

When I attempt to use Jake Wharton's [Android ThreeTen ABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library, in unit tests, I get an exception:

```
org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesException: No time-zone data files registered
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281808/threeten-backport-error-on-android-zonerulesexception-no-time-zone-data-files) explains that `init` may have not been called, but how do I do this in a unit test?

Comment: @OleV.V. not the same. This question is about using an alternative library for unit tests. That question is about forgetting to call `init`. I mentioned `init` in my answer just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is caused because `AndroidThreeTen.init` has not been called with a context.
[Local unit tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests) do not have an Application or a Context which are required for the Android Threeten ABP to load timezone information.

For unit tests, you can use the regular [ThreeTen BP](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp) which is not designed for Android. It can load the timezone info without an Android context. None of your imports will need to change.

Add the additional threeten library to your gradle file, using the `testImplementation` command.

```
implementation "com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.1"
testImplementation "org.threeten:threetenbp:1.4.0"
```

Note that the two version numbers do not coincide.